# Добавление префикса в xmlrootelement

Tags: java, xml

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно с помощью Marshaller сформировать xml - структуру наподобие :

```
<p:DCTRequest 
    xmlns:p="www.**.com" 
    xmlns:p1="www.**.com/datatypes"
    xmlns:p2="www.**.com/DCTRequestdatatypes"
    xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

</<p:DCTRequest >
```

Вот код моего класса :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;


@XmlRootElement (name = "DCTRequest")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class DCTRequestType { 

    @XmlElement(name = "GetQuote")
    protected GetQuoteType GetQuote ;


    public void setGetQuote (GetQuoteType quote){

        this.GetQuote = quote;

    }



    public GetQuoteType getGetQuote() {

        return this.GetQuote;

    }


}
```

Comment: XML структура: 
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://www.**.com" 
 xmlns:p1="http://www.**.com/datatypes" 
 xmlns:p2="http://www.**.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></<p:DCTRequest >

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно просто указать namespace, то есть два варианта.

Первый - указать в аннотации:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "DCTRequest", namespace = "http://***.com")
```

Второй - создаем в том же пакете файл **package-info.java** со следующим содержимым:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://***.com", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package your.package.name;
```

В обоих вариантах на выходе получим:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DCTRequest xmlns="http://***.com">
...
</DCTRequest>
```

Если обязательно нужно чтобы имя префикса было "p", тогда модифицируем во втором варианте **package-info.java**:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://***.com",
        xmlns = @XmlNs(prefix = "p", namespaceURI = "http://***.com"),
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package your.package.name;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

на выходе будет:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://***.com">
...
</p:DCTRequest>
```

Если нужно несколько префиксов, можно написать так:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "http://***.com",
        xmlns = {
                @XmlNs(prefix = "p", namespaceURI = "http://***.com"),
                @XmlNs(prefix = "p1", namespaceURI = "www.**.com/datatypes"),
                @XmlNs(prefix = "p2", namespaceURI = "www.**.com/DCTRequestdatatypes")
        },
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)

package test.aaa;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

и просто у элементов указывать namespace, а префиксы сами подставятся.

Comment: Добрый день.
Попробовал сделать как Вы сказали:

Comment: создал файл package-ino.java в проекте, но  почему-то Lotus не понимает той структуры, которую я хочу от него получить.<ns2:DCTRequest xmlns:ns2="http://www.dhl.com"> вот в таком виде формируется тег. Подскажите, что  может быть не так?

Comment: @RenatAhmetshin а при чем здесь Lotus и то что вы от него получаете? Речь идёт о том как сформировать xml в Java. Если вы в том же пакете где и DCTRequestType.java создадите package-info.java как я описал и укажете namespace у XmlRootElement и XmlElement - получите то что я написал. Если Lotus что-то не то отдаёт или что-то не то понимает, то это уже оформляйте в отдельный вопрос.